# can't convert np.ndarray of type numpy.object_. The only supported types are: float64, float32, float16, complex64, complex128, int64, int32, int16

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm trying to convert my data frame to a tensor.

```
df_1 = pd.read_csv(r'data/flight_data_set/flight.csv',
                   usecols= ['Airline name ', 'Travel  Time' ,'Number of  Stoppage ', 'Depreture  Airport', 'Depreture Time', '1st Stoppage Waiting Hour', '1st Stoppage', '2nd StoppageWaiting Time'])

train_x = torch.tensor(df_1.values)
```

I tried to change the array to a tensor, but it threw the error :

> can't convert np.ndarray of type numpy.object_. The only supported types are: float64, float32, float16, complex64, complex128, int64, int32, int16

Comment: show example of the data. possibly contain strings (or bad data). the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Because you have many string variables. You cant introduce strings to a NN. You need to tranform them to numbers first.